# Is it better to use oranges that are under-ripe or over-ripe to make marmalade?

Tags: food-preservation, jam

I have some slightly under-ripe oranges, and will be leaving the house shortly. Would I be wasting time to try to make them into marmalade?

Answer (score 3):

Under ripe oranges are actually desirable for marmalade, as they tend to have more pectin, which helps to give the marmalade its jammy, gelatinous consistency. So have at it!